# How do I determine what the data type is of a value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, types, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll, and have stored some information in `_data/some_data.yml`, which contains data like this:

```
---
links:
- http://example.org/some/data
- http://example.org/some/other/data
```

Another record, `_data/more_data.yml`, contains data like this:

```
---
links: http://example.com
```

A third record, `_data/yet_more_data.yml`, contains data like this:

```
---
links:
  "A title-based link": http://example.net
  "Another title-based link": https://example.net/some/other/page
```

I will be parsing the data sources in the template, like this:

```
<pre>
{% for a_record in site.data %}
  Parsing: {{ a_record[0] }}
  Links: 
    << PSUDOCODE >>
      {% if a_record[1].links is a string %}
        * [{{ a_record[1].links }}]({{ a_record[1].links }})
      {% elseif a_record[1].links is an array %}
        {% for link in a_record[1].links %}
          * [{{ link }}]({{ link }}]
        {% endfor %}
      {% elseif a_record[1].links is a hash %}
        {% for link in a_record[1].links %}
          * [{{ link[0] }}]({{ link[1] }})
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    << /PSUDOCODE >>
  - End Record -
{% endfor %}
</pre>
```

How can I work out if I'm looking at a string, an array or a hash?

I started writing a plugin to support this check, but it's not working out the way I expected - at all!

```
module Jekyll
  module IsAFilter
    def is_a_string(value)
      if not value.instance_of?(::Hash) 
        if not value.instance_of?(::Array)
          if value.instance_of?(::String)
            return true
          end
        end
      end
      return false
    end
    def is_a_hash(value)
      if not value.instance_of?(::Array)
        if value.instance_of?(::Hash)
          return true
        end
      end
      return false
    end
    def is_an_array(value)
      if not value.instance_of?(::Hash)
        if value.instance_of?(::Array)
          return true
        end
      end
      return false
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::IsAFilter)
```

To use that, I imagined that I could do `{% if a_record[1].links | is_a_string %}{{ a_record[1].links }}{% endif %}` but that always renders it as a string, even if it's an array or a hash?

And, before it's suggested, yes, I could say "you must always use the YAML hash format", but once I've finished writing this, I'm going to be handing control of the data to someone else, so I want to be sure that whatever they end up putting in there, it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby you can use `.is_a? DataType`. E.g.

```
[1] pry(main)> "hello".is_a? String
=> true
[2] pry(main)> {key: 1}.is_a? Hash
=> true
[3] pry(main)> [1,2,3].is_a? Array
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had it so close! Thanks to [@bashford7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66227877/5738), I amended my code to use the form `value.is_a? String`, but the problem was actually in my understanding of Jekyll...

I had to use this stanza:

```
{% assign check_variable = some_variable | some_filter_that_returns_true %}
{% if check_variable %}
USE THIS STANZA - IT WORKS
{% endif %}
```

Instead of what I assumed I could use, which was this stanza:

```
{% if some_variable | some_filter_that_returns_true %}
DON'T USE THIS STANZA - IT DOESN'T WORK
{% endif %}
```

My final plugin, if it's useful, looks like this:

```rb
module Jekyll
  module IsAFilters
    def is_a(value)
      return value.inspect
    end
    def is_a_string(value)
      if value.is_a? String
        return true
      end
      return false
    end
    def is_a_hash(value)
      if value.is_a? Hash
        return true
      end
      return false
    end
    def is_an_array(value)
      if value.is_a? Array
        return true
      end
      return false
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::IsAFilters)
```